# How to check if Laravel eloquent model has been refreshed?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, lumen

Is there any good way to check if model has already been refreshed ($model->refresh() has been called)? Or if model contains all the columns?

I am having problems with unnecessary double refreshes as some models are being refreshed during saving and some aren't. This is because the models that are sent via websocket are being refreshed and those that aren't sent via websocket aren't refreshed. I would like to check if model is refreshed or if it contains all the columns in controller so I would not double refresh the models that are already refreshed. This is needed because without refreshing I am not getting fields that were not set and are being set to default by database.

Currently only idea I have is to go through all the attributes and check if they exists but that doesn't seem the best idea.

Comment: What do you mean by refreshed? I understand you save your model, so you get your db's default value in your model? So if model is saved, it contains a valid `id`. If no valid `id`, then it is not saved yet. If you want to check if a model is new or you just updated an old model, you can use `if($model->wasRecentlyCreated === true)`

Comment: To clarify I mean $model->refresh(); function, which fetches the entire row from DB.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. So you sometimes have changes in the model and only want to refresh the models that have uncommited changes in them? Something like `if($model->isDirty()) $model->refresh();` ?

Comment: No all the data has been saved. And its all about refresh. If refresh hasn't been called data like timeCreated which is set by DB are missing. And I would like to have a proper way of checking if model contains all the columns in the controller. If it doesn't refresh would be called.

Comment: Ok, maybe upload some code that shows what you are doing and where you are double-loading the data? I mean, the only way you can fill in the missing data, is by retrieving it from the db. If possible(and that depends on the code), you might want to collect all the models that you saved. Then request them all from db at once, so you are not performing a query per model. Again, code examples would be nice in this case to be able to give more precise advice.